# Need to pass a connection through class/Method

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, excel

I have to import excel to SQL db. I have written all code as below on upload button.

But I have to write a class/method separately and not to write any sql at button click.

Kindly help me I am new to programming

**My Total Code:**

```
private void SaveFileToDatabase(string filePath)
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(filePath) == ".xls")
    {
        excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath);
    }
    else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath) == ".xlsx")
    {
        excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml'", filePath);
    }

    // Importing a file data to Database

    // Create Connection to Excel work book 
    OleDbConnection Oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = Oledbconn;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    Oledbconn.Open();
    DataTable dtSheet = Oledbconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    Oledbconn.Close();

    // iterate each sheet
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow sheet in dtSheet.Rows)
    {
        Oledbconn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sheetName = sheet["table_name"].ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from [" + sheetName + "]";
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        ISqlMapper sqlMapper = ApplicationContainer.Current.Resolve<ISqlMapper>("StageDB");
        ISqlMapSession SqlMapSession = sqlMapper.OpenConnection();
        SqlMapSession.Connection.Open();

        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlMapSession.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            // Destination table name.  Table name is sheet name minus any $
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = sheetName.Replace("$", "");
            foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
            }
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
        Oledbconn.Close();
        sqlMapper.CloseConnection();
    }

**The code which I have to make a class and just callhere:**

    ISqlMapper sqlMapper = ApplicationContainer.Current.Resolve<ISqlMapper>("StageDB");
    ISqlMapSession SqlMapSession = sqlMapper.OpenConnection();
    SqlMapSession.Connection.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlMapSession.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        // Destination table name.  Table name is sheet name minus any $
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = sheetName.Replace("$", "");
        foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
        {
            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
        }
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
    }
    Oledbconn.Close();
    sqlMapper.CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue exactly?  Are you asking how to create a class?

Comment: Yes I need to create a class/Method separately for SQL Bulkcopy and just have to call that on page so that not use sql at page load.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a lot of success using the `DbDataReader` object associated with a SQL command when bulk inserting data into SQL Server.  I've used it where the source data is a number of different DBMS platforms.  Admittedly, I've never done this with a spreadsheet as source, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

This is untested, but it should get you a large part of the way there:

```
OleDbConnection Oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString);
Oledbconn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", Oledbconn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 120000;
copy.DestinationTableName = "MyTable";

// presupposes the columns line up, as they do in your example

for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetName(i));

copy.WriteToServer(reader);

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
Oledbconn.Close();
```